# callback after remove() to avoid effects take place at the same time

Tags: jquery, callback

How Can I string these two statements together so the fadeIn of the loader does not happen when the items are faded out.
A callback after remove?

```
$(pager).css('margin-top', '180px');
content.find('div.item').fadeTo(500, 0.2, function () {
    content.find('div.item').remove();
})
$("#content-lader").fadeIn(1000, function () {
    content.html('<div id="content-lader">&nbsp;</div>' + data.content);
    $(pager).css('margin-top', '0px');
});
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var c = 0;
var totItem = content.find('div.item').length;

content.find('div.item').fadeTo(500, 0.2, function () {
    $(this).remove();
    c++;
    if(c == totItem){
        $("#content-lader").fadeIn(1000, function () {
           content.html('<div id="content-lader">&nbsp;</div>' + data.content);
           $(pager).css('margin-top', '0px');
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, interesting, diddn't know you could do it with a counter, I don't even see a loop

Comment: that was beoutyfull - 10 points ( how do you spell beautifull? )

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why to use an if and a var for mgraph's answer. I believe calling your fadeIn method from inside fadeOut's callback should work just fine too.

AKA:

```
content.find('div.item').fadeTo(500, 0.2, function () {
    $(this).remove();

    $("#content-lader").fadeIn(1000, function () {
           content.html('<div id="content-lader">&nbsp;</div>' + data.content);
           $(pager).css('margin-top', '0px');
    });

})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w45p/mZWUW/